# table backround color with transparency

Tags: tables, xetex, color, transparency

Target:
[image: I would like to have this]
I would like to use a table where each second row is colored slightly gray. but i also have a backgrund image on the page so just using `\rowcolors` with standart colors isnt working.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}    

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
color=black,
contents={%
 \ifodd\value{page}
   \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Images/Backgrounds/HeXXenBG_Left_LQ}}
  \else
   \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Images/Backgrounds/HeXXenBG_Right_LQ}}
  \fi
    }
}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{black!40}{}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
{\scshape Spalte 1}&{\scshape Spalte 2}&{\scshape Spalte 3}&{\scshape Spalte 4}\\\hline\hline
Beispiel 1 & Hier geht mehr rein. & A & Die Tabelle sollte sich an die Textspalten halten\\
Beispiel 2 & Genauso hier. & B & Das musst du manuell machen.leider\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Current:
[image: this is what i got]
is there some possibility for activate multiply blend mode, for table background color?
or some other workaround?

Edit:
i am compiling with xelatex, so the duplicate is not working

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please provide us with the code that you have tried? (No one here is keen on punching in tables from scratch just to see that this table was not what you're looking for.)

Comment: Looking for something like this?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457202/28557

Comment: i am trying to develop an command or environment, which can be used more easily, than editing each row/cell manually

Comment: @lukasester Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that includes all necessary packages to compile your code? E.g. where is `\backgroundsetup` coming from?

Comment: sorry, i updated the code to a working MWE (except for the Image) i do not know how to create a structured background image by code except for maybe tikz. The problem. I also included the condition to work with xelatex and even tested the "original of this duplicate" which does not work. not even without xelatex. because the other solution works with colorbox and not background.

Comment: without xelatex https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62528/36296 works fine with your MWE. It does not matter if it uses a colourbox or an background image, the colours are still semi-transparent.

Comment: indeed, it does. i just didnt look close enough. but i have to use xelatex. so i am still hoping there is some possiblity to do this

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have the same requirement.